# How do I insert a mysql spatial point with a yii model?

Tags: mysql, yii, geospatial, spatial

I have a model type that was generated from a mysql table that has address data and also a spatial `POINT` field named "coordinates".  When a model is created or updated I want to geocode the address and store the latitude and longitude coordinates in the `POINT` field.

My understanding is the way to do this is to geocode the address in the model's `beforeSave` method.  I have done this and have the coordinates in an associative array.  Now my question is how can I insert this data into my coordinates field?  This is what I'm trying:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $singleLineAddress = $this->getSingleLineAddress();
    $coords = Geocoder::getCoordinates($singleLineAddress);

    // WORKS: using the following line works to insert POINT(0 0)
    //$this->coordinates = new CDbExpression("GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)')");

    // DOESN'T WORK: using the following line gives an error
    $this->coordinates = new CDbExpression("GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lng)')",
        array(':lat' => $coords['lat'], ':lng' => $coords['lng'] ));

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

When I do this I get the following error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]:
>   Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `place`
>   (`city`, `state`, `name`, `street`, `postal_code`, `phone`, `created`,
>   `coordinates`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5,
>   UTC_TIMESTAMP(), GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lng)'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
 $this->coordinates = new CDbExpression("GeomFromText(:point)",
        array(':point'=>'POINT('.$coords['lat'].' '.$coords['lng'].')'));
```

Comment: sorry should have mentioned that I'd had tried this also and it gives the same error

Comment: actually I was wrong, this works.  I tried so many variations I thought I had tried this.

Answer (score 5):

Small edit in @dlnGd0nG 's answer if you are using **Yii 2**

```
$this->coordinates = new yii\db\Expression("GeomFromText(:point)",
    array(':point'=>'POINT('.$coords['lat'].' '.$coords['lng'].')'));
```